# Stopping a service in TopShelf Manually

Tags: c#, topshelf

Using TopShelf, how do I stop a service manually? I have looked into the documentation and have found that to stop a service you have to use the command prompt, like so:

service.exe [Servicename] stop

When I use that, I found that it just starts the service all over again without stopping it.

Answer (score 2):

To stop a service from the command-line, assuming the service.exe was written using Topshelf, the command-line arguments would be:

```
service.exe stop
```

If you need to upgrade to administrator, use:

```
service.exe stop --sudo
```

That will bring up UAC to upgrade to administrator.

If your service was installed with an instance name (by default most are NOT), you would use:

```
service.exe stop --instance:MyInstanceName
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html), the command line should be:

> service.exe stop -instance:Servicename

Comment: I see. I understand the documentation better now thanks to your example there. Unfortunately, when I run the command that way, nothing happens.

Comment: @Vakey Have you solved the problem? What was a cause?